# React Native Linking External App

Tags: android, ios, react-native

**Question**

Inside my react native app, I want to launch an external app called "Taco Shop". I am using the package react-native-app-link. I want to launch this app from within my app, but if not installed, take the user to the app store.

**Code**

```
var url = "tacoshop://";  <-----NO CLUE WHERE OR HOW I GET THIS URL
var appName = 'Taco Shop';
var appStoreId = 'id1185454813';
var playStoreId = 'io.simplyorder.tacoshop';


AppLink.maybeOpenURL(url, { appName, appStoreId, playStoreId }).then(() => {
  // do stuff
})
.catch((err) => {
  // handle error
});
```

It launches the google play/app store, but does not launch the actual app when installed. How do I find the URL above of the taco shop app to launch directly if installed?

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Comment: @SwapnilPatwa no I didn't. I ended up just linking to the app store for now. Still searching

Answer (score 0):

Taco Shop needs to implement Deep Links.  It doesn't look like it does.  To fake Deep Links for an app that doesn't have deep links implemented, you can use something like this to do so: https://portal.deeplink.me/